# My four year old is out of control

Tags: behavior, pre-schooler

My son is four and he has a really bad temper. He'll get up and go to school and when he gets home there'll be a note stating whether he was good or bad. Most day's are good but he gets into moods where he wants to act up and kick his class mates.

When he gets home, he'll watch some TV but right after that he'll start to play with his younger brother, who is almost eleven months old. He starts to push him, hit him, he even pushed him off the couch and he hit his head on the table.

I've tried time out, no TV, number of things and it just doesn't seem to work, please.... I need some help

Comment: Maybe he has too much energy, gets frustrated and ends up acting bad because of this? You could try going to the park after school to get him to burn some energy.

Answer (score 5):

A great way to proceed here is to try and discover the source of your child's frustration.

Some common sources of frustration:

Has your child's routine recently changed?
Is your child feeling jealous of the time you spend with his younger brother?
Does he feel that he's unable to communicate his thoughts?
Is your child getting enough rest during the night?

At four years old your child should be able to answer these questions if asked calmly in conversation.  Try asking how he feels about school, his brother, as you may find many more details through a calm conversation.

Comment: Given the time of the year for this posting, I'm going to guess that it's a combination of everything you mentioned.  School recently started in a lot of places and that is a huge deal for a child.